# In a cylinder lying on its side one fourth full , how high is water in it?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

Seems like a simple question to get the formula for the area of a circle segment and to solve for h. The problem is, I have to solve this equation for x first, in :
$$  \frac{\pi}{4}=\left(\frac{r^2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{360}x-\sin(x)\right)  $$

is the fraction of area of the remaining water, the length of the cylinder is irrelevant)

but unfortunately, it seems no calculator in the world is able to solve this for x, because it has an x both inside and outside of a trigonometric function. Is there another way to solve this or, is my calculator just not good enough?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Proper formatting is expected; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user1510024 Convert *both* the  $ x  $ to radians.

Comment: I don't see how this helps solving this: a=x-sin(x), which is the root of the problem

Comment: "no calculator in the world is able to solve this": the solution has no closed-form expression, but numerous calculators have a numerical root finder which will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In radians and with $r=1$, the equation is

$$x-\sin x=\frac{\pi}4$$ or $$x=\sin x+\frac\pi4.$$

As you pointed, it has no closed-form expression as the unknown appears both inside and outside the trigonometric function.

You can obtain a numerical estimate by the fixed-point method, using a simple scientific calculator. Indeed, the iterations

$$x_{n+1}=\sin x_n+\frac\pi4$$ will converge to the root ($1.76634028\cdots$) from any starting value.

---

For the sake of illustration, here are the first four iterates of the function, clearly showing that it tends to a constant.

[image]

---

Faster convergence is obtained by Newton's iterations,

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n-\sin x_n-\frac\pi4}{1-\cos x_n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1&2

It is a transcendental equation, many hand held calculators do the job.You have not applied radian measure throughout. Secondly after stating that $r$ does not matter for angle you brought it in again into equation.

If  $t$ is half apex angle in radian measure,

> FindRoot[Pi/4. == ( 2 t - Sin[2 t]) , {t, .5}]

gives $ t \approx 0.883.$

Comment: mine doesn't, I even tried this: 1=x-sin(x)

Comment: Thanks. I know..I am only  trying to help/nudge him, not give an answer so early in his attempts. He seems not to have tried it out himself.